# VGA and HDMI monitors on laptop extended sisplay

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, so forgive me if it's not.

I own a MSI GE60 laptop, and got Ubuntu 16.04 on it (don't know if it matters for the question).
This laptop has 1 VGA port and 1 HDMI port, would I be able to use those both at the same time with extended display, so I would have 3 screens to use, drag and drop stuff?

Comment: What kind of Graphics card do you have in the laptop?

Comment: I have a Nvidia gtx950m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to re-install nvidia settings:

Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```

then to confirm it installed go to (in terminal):

```
nvidia-settings
```

then you'll see something like this screen: nVidia xserver settings

[image]

From the left pane,

- choose X Server Display Configuration
- click the secondary screen in the dialog window click Configure.
- Enable TwinView. If it doesn't
  work immediately, reboot the computer.

*Credit to: [Fabby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856247/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-adding-external-monitor-stretches-single-display-across) (modified their answer to contribute more to this problem)*